# Clear variables

Tags: notebooks

I'm new in Mathematica and I am working with various notebooks. My problem is that when I run a notebook, it seems taking definitions from the previous notebook. For example in 'notebook1' I make an approximation like E=M, and when I run the second notebook it takes also the approximation instead I don't want it to do it. I've tried commands like 'Clear' or 'ClearAll' but I can't get through. Can anybody help me? Thanks

Comment: `ClearAll[var]`?

Comment: I've tried ClearAll[var], but it seems not working...Maybe could be something like the evaluation context? thanks

Comment: Well, you can still quit the kernel or in the menu _/evaluation/Notebook's Default Context/Unique to This Context_

Comment: I've also tried None Kernel and make the context unique to that notebook, but it's still not working

Comment: Thanks, I solved it quitting the Kernel. Thank you so much

Comment: Alternatively, you can use the menu item Evaluation / Notebook's Default Context / Unique to this Notebook. This will "isolate" each notebook for which you select this option. Be warned that this causes some side-effects, because `Context[]` is no longer `Global`, but this shouldn't affect what you are doing.